# Скорость селекторов jQuery

Tags: jquery, выборка, производительность

Подскажите, чем измерить скорость выборки селекторами jQuery? Раньше для FF был java.console, но, к сожалению, он уже не обновляется, а на новых версиях лисы не пашет.

Нужен именно плагин, а не какой-либо он-лайн сервис.

---

**Решение**: Чтобы измерить скорость выборки, пишем в JS коде:

```
console.time("имя");
выборка с помощью 1 или нескольких селекторов
console.timeEnd("то же имя");
```

И в консоли Firebug будет писаться время выборки, если между time и timeEnd была только выборка. Между запуском и остановкой таймера можно запихнуть что угодно, и будет измеряться, соответственно, общее время выполнения этой части скрипта.

P.S. В DragonFly оперы в консоли также все работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FireBug думаю поможет

Comment: Да стоит firebug, но что-то я не видел в нем функции замера скорости выборки. AJAX запросы - да, показывает. А вот скорость работы селекторов не в курсе где смотреть

Comment: не разбирался полностью, но может быть http://code.google.com/intl/ru/speed/page-speed/docs/using_firefox.html поможет

Comment: page-speed тоже стоит, но он не делает того, что нужно, он измеряет общую скорость загрузки страницы и выдает всяческие рекомендации по оптимизации. Время выборки селекторами он так-же не показывает

Comment: Все, разобрался, каким-то чудным образом заработал console на 8 версии FF. Добавил решение в свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Самый не удобный и бесполезный способ. В файрфоксе результаты будут отличаться незначительно, куда интересней измерить скорость различных селекторов в других браузерах, таких как ие, там выигрыш во времени от оптимизации селекторов будет просто громадным, Можете посмотреть скорость различных селекторов у всех популярных js-библиотек в тесте [slicktest](http://mootools.net/slickspeed/). Если общей информации не достаточно, можете скачать его и запустить локально, заменив предложенные селекторы на ваши и тестировать именно на вашем документе. Можно сразу тестировать везде, а не только в удобном файрбаге.

Comment: Ну тут позволю с вами не согласиться. Если, допустим, селектор по дереву пробегает за 100мс, а я оптимизировал его до 10мс (т.е. стало в 10 раз быстрее), то соответственно от изначального что в лисе, что в ишаке будет в 10 раз быстрее. К тому же console.profile() очень хорошо считает количество запросов на выборку, что тоже очень удобно. Вчера было, что изначально селектор выполнялся около 400-ми запросами, оптимизировал, стало 23. Соответственно и время уменьшилось.

Answer (score 1):

Скорость отработки того или иного селектора в значительной мере будет зависеть от куска DOM на котором его применить.

Чтобы грамотно использовать селекторы нужно понять, как работает движок sizzle, который и занимается их анализом и парсингом DOM.

Очень хорошо об этом написано тут: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/111195/